# Run SQL Job that will run SSIS package to import from excel to (Azure) Database

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-core, azure-sql-database

I want to have a .net Core MVC application.
I want to be able to import from a excel file to the database. I think the DB will be on AZURE.
I know that it's a possibility to upload via SSIS Package which is called by a SQL Job.
How can I do that in .Net Core?
Or you have another solution to import via excel to DB?

Comment: Can we assume the Excel file will be uploaded to an Azure Storage account and from there you want it to be imported?

Comment: Yes we can if we assume that a logged in user with custom login will be able to import it at any time.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a Database Scoped Credential to access your Azure Storage Account.

```
CREATE DATABASE SCOPED CREDENTIAL UploadInvoices  
WITH IDENTITY = 'SHARED ACCESS SIGNATURE',
SECRET = 'QLYMgmSXMklt%2FI1U6DcVrQixnlU5Sgbtk1qDRakUBGs%3D';
```

Then create an External Data Source.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL DATA SOURCE MyAzureInvoices
    WITH  (
        TYPE = BLOB_STORAGE,
        LOCATION = 'https://newinvoices.blob.core.windows.net', 
        CREDENTIAL = UploadInvoices  
    );
```

And finally import the Excel file to your database as shown below.

```
BULK INSERT Colors2
FROM 'week3/inv-2017-01-19.csv'
WITH (DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
      FORMAT = 'CSV');
```

You can query the Excel file also, as shown below:

```
SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET(
BULK  'week3/inv-2017-01-19.csv',
DATA_SOURCE = 'MyAzureInvoices',
SINGLE_CLOB) AS DataFile;
```

For more information, please visit [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/import-export/examples-of-bulk-access-to-data-in-azure-blob-storage?view=sql-server-2017) documentation.

You can put all this on a stored procedure and create a scheduled tasks using [Azure Automation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-automation).

Although [this](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-blobs-dotnet-export-import-excel-blob-to-from-db) sample application is not build on DotNet Core you may find it useful.